# CakePHP HABTM find ONLY associated model data

Tags: cakephp

I have the following relations:

```
class Platformuser extends AppModel {
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Service'
 );
}    

class Service extends AppModel {
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Platformuser'
 );
}
```

I am doing a action on the PlatformusersController to get the services associated with this user with the following query:

```
$this->Platformuser->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('Platformuser.id' => $userId),
));
```

It returns everything about Platformuser/Service and I ONLY want the data of the service:

```
array(
(int) => array(
    [Platformuser] => array(
        [id] => [1]
        [name] => [Domingo]
    ),
    [Service] => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
                [id] => [1]
                [name] => [dropbox],
                [PlatformusersService] => array(
                   [id] => [1],
                   [platformuser_id] => [1],
                   [service_id] => [1],
                   [modified] => [2013-10-10 00:00:00],
                   [created] => [2013-10-10 00:00:00];
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I want something like:

```
array(
    [Service] => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
                [id] => [1]
                [name] => [dropbox]
        )
    )
```

Any ideas?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the containable behavior. It's easy to use and you'll able to fetch data according to your need like.

```
 $plateFormuser = $this->Platformuser->find('first', array(
     'conditions' => array('Platformuser.id' => $userId),
     'contain' => array(
         'Service' => array(
             'fields' => array('id', 'name') 
         )
      )
    ));

 $services = Set::merge(
        Set::classicExtract($plateFormuser, 'Service.{n}.{id}'),
        Set::classicExtract($plateFormuser, 'Semester.{n}.{name}')
 );
```

Now you can json encode the $services to get result as you've mentioned `[{"id":"1", "name":"dropbox"}]`.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, getting: [
  [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "PlatformusersService" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "service_id" : "1",
        "created" : "2013-10-10 00:00:00",
        "modified" : "2013-10-10 00:00:00",
        "platformuser_id" : "1"
      },
      "name" : "dropbox"
    }]]

Comment: How to tell the contain to not fetch the HABTM table info?. Also, do you know why I get a double array (in the beginning)?. Should be: [{"id":"1", "name":"dropbox"}]  (data is json'd).

Comment: I will accept the answer if you know how to ignore the HABTM data.

Comment: I dont think it is possible in cakephp

Comment: I've updated the answere. You can extract or exclude the fields with Set::classicExtract().